# How to make a variable equate to another variable (Python)

Tags: python, variables, random, printing, equals

I don't even know how to explain this one.

```
Question1 = "a" 
Question2 = "b" 
Question3 = "c" 
Question4 = "d"
Question5 = "e"
```

etc.

```
Answer1 = "a" 
Answer2 = "b" 
Answer3 = "c" 
Answer4 = "d" 
Answer5 = "e"
```

etc.

```
questioninteger = random.randint(1,20)
if(questioninteger == 1):
    Boolean1 = True
    Question == Question1
    Answer == Answer1
    FlashCard()
if(questioninteger == 2):
    Boolean2 = True
    Question == Question2
    Answer == Answer2
    FlashCard()
if(questioninteger == 3):
    Boolean3 = True
    Question == Question3
    Answer == Answer3
    FlashCard()
```

etc.

```
print("")
print(Question)
print("")
key = raw_input()
if(key == Answer):
    print("Correct!")
    time.sleep(1)
    QuestionPicker()
```

(all are within functions)

Problem is Python won't change the variable Question, and no error comes up. 'Answer is successfully changed, 'Question' just won't be.

Comment: You have equality checks (like `Question == Question3`) instead of assignments. Change to assignments and retry.

Comment: it also looks like you would benefit from looking up how to use [`dicts`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Comment: Thank jesus for you, it works. Turns out I tried that earlier, but hadn't globalised Question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are generally a bad idea; you would do well to rewrite your code to something like

```
from random import choice
from time import sleep

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, options, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.options  = options
        self.answer   = answer

    def ask(self):
        print("\n" + self.question)
        for opt in self.options:
            print(opt)
        response = input().strip()
        return (response == self.answer)

# define a list of questions
questions = [
    Question("What is 10 * 2?",                 ["5", "10", "12", "20", "100"],            "20"),
    Question("Which continent has alligators?", ["Africa", "South America", "Antarctica"], "South America")
]

# ask a randomly chosen question
def ask_a_question(questions):
    q      = choice(questions)
    got_it = q.ask()
    sleep(1)
    if got_it:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, the proper answer is " + q.answer)
```